# How do I make and fill and array of enum type

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

I am trying to make an array int indexed but I want the values to be of an specific enum type. The part I am having trouble with is how to fill the array without having to hard code it i.e

```
int main(){
    enum Color{blue=0, green, brown,orange,black}
    Color colors[5];

    for(int i = blue; i!= black;i++){
        colors[i]=i;//this is the part the compiler does not like
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colors[i] = static_cast<Color>(i);
```

Note that your loop iterates four times and assigns four colors, indexed 0 through 3, `blue` through `orange`. `colors[4]` remains uninitialized.

Comment: Also due to `i!= black` the last element stays uninitialized.

Comment: I was expecting something like Java casting, thanks! It worked!

Comment: maybe this should be a different question but how would I print the enum values not their int counter part?

Comment: If you want to print actual strings "blue", "green" and so on, then somewhere in your program string literals "blue", "green" and so on must appear. C++ doesn't provide any built-in way to obtain a string from a variable of enum type, if that's what you are asking. Those names, just like variable names, exist only at compile time.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Then that part should be coded. Thanks! @IgorTandetnik

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change your loop counter to a `Color` instead of an `int`:

```
for(Color i = blue; i!= black;i++)
```

Comment: @AlexD Doh! Been a while since I used enums in C++. This trick would work in C...